# Meteor JS, split up every N items into their own table

Tags: javascript, html, meteor

So I've got some rows, which im putting into tables. They come from one source, currently I'm showing them all in the regular fashion -

```
  {{#each rows}}
   {{> rowTemplate}}
  {{/each}}
```

Which gives me a dom like this

```
<table class="ui table celled">
  <thead>
    ...
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>....</tr>
    <tr>....</tr>
    ...
  </tbody>
</table>
```

What I want to do is split them up into groups of N, all coming from the single data source. So instead of all the rows being in one giant table, if N = 6, the dom would end up looking like -

```
<table>
 //first 6 rows
</table>

<table>
 //next 6 rows
</table>

etc
```

This is proving to be rather tricky actually. I've been trying to get it done with at first a custom helper as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16631395/handlebars-and-meteorjs-for-every-other-or-number), but it's not working in the latest version of meteor, due to changes to the layout engine.

Any suggestions about the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example helper for partitioning the documents:

```
// returns an array of objects like:
// [{rows: [doc1...docn]}, {rows: [docn+1...docn+n]}]
var partitionTables = function(documents, tableSize) {
  var tables = [];
  _.each(documents, function(doc, i) {
    var tableNumber = Math.floor(i / tableSize);
    if (tables[tableNumber] == null)
      tables[tableNumber] = {rows: []};
    tables[tableNumber].rows.push(doc);
  });
  return tables;
};

Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  tables: function() {
    // fetch some documents - change this line for your app
    var documents = Collection.find().fetch();

    // partition the documents into an array of objects
    return partitionTables(documents, 6);
  }
});
```

You can use it in your template like this:

```
{{#each tables}}
  <table>
    <tbody>
      {{#each rows}}
        <tr>{{this}}</tr>
      {{/each}}
    </tbody>
  </table>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Works great! The _.each function wasn't working for me, so I changed it to use .forEach.

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

`{{#each rows}}`

The context of that block is the entire set of rows. Change the context to be an array of "6 row arrays".

i.e. `var sixRowBlock = [[1,2,3,4,5,6], [1,2,3,4,5,6]]`

Then you can just do something like this.

```
{{#each sixRowBlock}}
    <table>
        {{#each this}}{{/each}}
    </table>
{{/each}}
```